# Using drag and drop to build an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to build a cake dragging some items to it, and then that I can download the image with all of the items dragged, But I don't want the image of the item disappears , I want that count every time that I drag it. 
Has anyone built something like this before?
I need an example please, I have to do it in javascript or Jquery.

This is my gui:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubY23.jpg]

Comment: Would you please add more information on this? what libraries are you using, any sample code snippet (fiddle, jsbin) etc. It would be easier to get answers if you could provide more information here.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what exactly you are after, I assume that you are looking for a kind of shopping cart solution. jQueryUI Droppable appears to be the simplest way to do that, check out this basic example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Shopping Cart Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  h1 { padding: .2em; margin: 0; }
  #products { float:left; width: 500px; margin-right: 2em; }
  #cart { width: 200px; float: left; margin-top: 1em; }
  /* style the list to maximize the droppable hitarea */
  #cart ol { margin: 0; padding: 1em 0 1em 3em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#catalog" ).accordion();
    $( "#catalog li" ).draggable({
      appendTo: "body",
      helper: "clone"
    });
    $( "#cart ol" ).droppable({
      activeClass: "ui-state-default",
      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
        $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
      }
    }).sortable({
      items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
      sort: function() {
        // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
        // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="products">
  <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Products</h1>
  <div id="catalog">
    <h2><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></h2>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Lolcat Shirt</li>
        <li>Cheezeburger Shirt</li>
        <li>Buckit Shirt</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="#">Bags</a></h2>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Zebra Striped</li>
        <li>Black Leather</li>
        <li>Alligator Leather</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="#">Gadgets</a></h2>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>iPhone</li>
        <li>iPod</li>
        <li>iPad</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cart">
  <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Shopping Cart</h1>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">
    <ol>
      <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart